# How os.walk work along with break statement?

Tags: python, for-loop, break, os.walk

I have the following code...

```
for i,v in df_activity.iterrows():
    folder = v["HDFS Location"].split('/')[-1]
    print(i)
    rootdir = '/home/gpumodel/simulation_26_aug/' + folder
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".json"):
                print(subdir)
                ......
                ......(some process)
                if condition:
                    index_viz_from.append(minval)
                    index_viz_to.append(maxval)
                    break
                break
```

My folder path kind of look like this

```
/home/gpumodel/simulation_26_aug/Khopoli_1/FibreShot/2019-08-28/1/10
```

The files inside the folder are this

```
part-00000-d57261c3-e707-4a76-b84c-6576741ecaa2-c000.json  part-00000-e65e0c7e-dfb1-4ca6-b622-17ef8622da04-c000.json  part-00000-e68fa877-4bff-4bff-aecb-c9cc0847c7db-c000.json  _SUCCESS
```

I would like to know how the above code works. From  what I understand the code recursively go until json files are there,when it processed one json file it encounters first `break` statement and goes out from `for in files` and after that does it go to `for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):` or goes to second `break` statement?

From how the program is working it goes to `for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):`. Why it doesnt go to second `break` statment. Is it because of the indendation given? Had the `break` given one indent before would the working have been different?

The output of my code is as below:

```
/home/gpumodel/simulation_26_aug/Khopoli_46/FibreShot/2019-08-29/1/10

/home/gpumodel/simulation_26_aug/Khopoli_47/FibreShot/2019-08-29/1/11

/home/gpumodel/simulation_26_aug/Khopoli_47/FibreShot/2019-08-29/1/10

/home/gpumodel/simulation_26_aug/Khopoli_48/FibreShot/2019-08-29/1/11
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, the `break` inside the if-statement is redundant. You don't need it because after the if-statement you immediately break anyway. The code should work exactly the same way if you remove the `break` inside the if-statement.

Also, `break` only affects loops, not if-statements. You don't "break out of an if-statement". `break` takes you out of the current loop. It prematurely stops the current, most-local loop, whatever it happens to be.

Comment: So the first break statement takes me out of "for file in files"  and it goes to 2nd for loop ryt?

Comment: The way your code is written, either of the two `break` statements (the first in the if-statement, or the second one) will take you out of the `for file in files` loop into the `for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir)` loop.